# jQuery - existing of document parent

Tags: jquery

Found a few similar articles, but can't seem to get anything to work.

We have this code as follows:

```
parent.$("#toTop").trigger("click");
```

However, we need to check for the existence of the parent element as it is throwing an error in some cases where dom setup is different:

```
parent.$(...) is null
```

How would I do that?

Comment: if(parent.$("#toTop")).....

Comment: yep, that works, make it an answer. Many thanks.

Comment: what kind of jQuery syntax is `parent.$(selector)` supposed to be?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
if(parent.$("#toTop")){//Not true if is undefined / null 
//codes
}
```

It is probably safer to use

```
if(parent.$("#toTop").length)){
    //codes
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if( parent && parent.$("#toTop")) {
    parent.$("#toTop").trigger("click");
}
```

If you are specifically looking only for the parent you can use this

```
if( parent )
```

There might be a case when the parent gives you a `empty` selector. So you can check for the length in such cases..

```
if(parent.length)
```